# Subtract matrix from ndarray along particular dimension without reshape

Tags: python, numpy

Supposing I have a 2 x 2 x 100 ndarray called `ahat` and a 2 x 2 matrix called `A`. What is the most pythonic way to subtract the 2 x 2 matrix from along the dimension of size 100 without looping or reshaping?

```
for k in range(ahat.shape[2]):
    ahat[:,:,k] = ahat[:,:, k] - A
```

I tried using `np.apply_over_axes` but couldn't get it to work. More generally if I have two ndarrays of compatible shapes like in the example above, what is preferred way to operate along a particular dimension. For the example I might want to multiply every 2x2 matrix in `ahat` with `A` or I might want to apply `np.linalg.inv` along the dimension of size 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promote `A` to an array of shape (2,2,1), then [NumPy broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) will do the rest:

```
ahat -= A[..., None]
```

`A[..., None]` is equivalent to `A[..., np.newaxis]`. It adds a new axis of length 1 to the array. Since `ahat` has shape (2,2,100), and `A[..., None]` has shape (2,2,1), NumPy broadcasting will promote both arrays to the compatible shape (2,2,100) (but in a memory-efficient way, *without* actually copying values from `A` to a larger array).

More generally, note that NumPy broadcasting will automatically add new axes to the left-side of the shape of any NumPy array. So, for example, with any basic NumPy arithmetic operation such as addition or multiplication, `A` would automatically broadcast to a shape like (1,2,2) if the other array involved in the arithmetic operation were 3-dimensional, (or even (1,1,2,2) if the other array were 4-dimensional). Above, we needed `A[..., None]` to explicitly add a new axis, since we wanted the new axis to be on the right-hand side of the shape.

---

For matrix multiplication, you would usually use `np.dot`, or `np.einsum`, or `np.tensordot`. Some of these functions, like `np.einsum` and `np.tensordot` allow you to specify which axes you wish to use in the matrix multiplication (so you would not need to add new axes explicitly).
For example, to matrix multiply `ahat` and `A`, you could use

```
np.tensordot(ahat, A, axes=[[1], [0]])
```

or

```
np.einsum('ijk,jl->ikl', ahat, A)
```

This multiplies values along the 1-axis of `ahat` with values along the 0-axis of `A`, and then sums to products.

Comment: Does this generally works with other operations in the question like matrix multiplication, or inversion?

Comment: @ITA: Your question about applying `np.linalg.inv` to each 2x2 array in an array of shape `(2,2,100)` is an interesting one. As far as I know, you would have to call `np.linalg.inv` once for each 2x2 array... or maybe, if you reshape the array into a big block matrix of shape (200, 200) with the 2x2s along the (block) diagonal you might be able to compute the inverse of all of them with one call to `np.linalg.inv`.

Comment: I hadn't thought about the number of function calls. One way I had thought of was using `np.moveaxis` to make it 100 x 2 x 2 and then calling `map()` with `np.linalg.inv`, more pythonic, but still 100 calls.

Comment: Another way to compute the inverses would be: `np.apply_along_axis(lambda arr: np.linalg.inv(arr.reshape(2,2)), axis=0, arr=ahat.reshape(-1, 100))`. But this just syntactic sugar -- under the hood `np.linalg.inv` is getting called 100 times in a for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the accepted answer, in case someone was wondering which of the two for inverting is faster (from the comments):

```
import timeit

setup='''import numpy as np
x = np.random.randint(0,100,(3,3,10000))'''


stm1 = 'xinv1 = np.moveaxis(np.asarray(list(map(np.linalg.inv, np.moveaxis(x,2,0)))),0,2)'
stm2 = 'np.apply_along_axis(lambda arr: np.linalg.inv(arr.reshape(3,3)), axis=0, arr=x.reshape(-1, 10000))'

times = timeit.repeat(setup = setup, stmt = stm1, number=100)
print('Using map: ', times)
times = timeit.repeat(setup = setup, stmt = stm2, number=100)
print('Using apply_along_axis: ', times)
```

gave me:

```
Using map:  [5.976081462009461, 6.024182428998756, 6.218410155008314]
Using apply_along_axis:  [8.279263457996421, 7.926949607004644, 7.928437952010427]
```